# My image status in the Dashbord always is already line up

Tags: openstack, openstack-glance

My image status in the Dashbord always is already line up.

[image]

In the VM I use command to list it, it is exists:

```
[root@ha-node1 neutron]# glance image-list 
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+
| ID                                   | Name                |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+
| 303f912b-a7e6-45f8-8219-7dc406d8e111 | cirros-0.3.4-x86_64 |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

And if I create instance form the dashboard, there is not image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it.

1. ensure the image file permission to be `glance:glance`:

   `chown glance:glance  cirros-0.3.4-x86_64-disk.img`
2. ensure the image store directory permission to `glance:glance`:

   `chown -R glance:glance /var/lib/glance/images`
3. In the `/etc/glance/glance-api.conf`:

   under the `[glance_store]`, the stores I changed to this:

   `stores = file,http,glance.store.filesystem.Store,glance.store.http.Store`

Then re-upload the image it should work.